# SwiftUI: Trigger event after scrolling to end of a paged tabview

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to have a prompt be called after a user reaches the end of a paged TabView and tries to scroll one extra. (For example, if there are three pages, once the user scrolls to the third page and tries to scroll to a fourth, it pulls up the prompt). I tried doing this:

```
TabView (selection: $currentIndex) {
   ...
}
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
.onChange(of: currentIndex) { _ in

}
```

However, since the user is already on the last tab, the index isn't updated so the prompt can't be called. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would try: add a fourth (dummy) tab; when scrolled to that, show prompt and set currentIndex to 3

Comment: How about simply using a drag gesture that is set up to read it if it is a swipe? The same motion that would cause navigation to the next page would trigger the prompt.

Comment: @ChrisR this would still show the the whole dummy view before scrolling back correct? Preferably, it'd prompt after a short scroll

Comment: @Yrb I tried using a drag gesture, however when it's put as a modifier to a tabview it seems to only like to register when swipes are happening in a perpendicular direction rather than the same direction as the tabview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't this work for you?. It reacts after showing 1/2 of the last (dummy) view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var currentIndex = 0
    @State private var showAlert = false
    
    let colors: [Color] = [.blue, .green, .cyan, .teal, .clear]

    var body: some View {
        
        TabView (selection: $currentIndex) {
            ForEach(0..<5) { i in
                ZStack {
                    colors[i]
                    Text("Tab \(currentIndex)")
                        .font(.title)
                }
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        
        .onChange(of: currentIndex) { _ in
            if currentIndex == 4 {
                currentIndex = 3
                showAlert = true
            }
        }
        .alert("You reached the end", isPresented: $showAlert) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, and it looked a little glitchy at first. adding .animation(.default, value: currentIndex) did the trick though.